# Magento 2 : How to override files from Magento core framework?

Tags: overrides, magento2.3, preference

Actually I'm refering to [#19247](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/19247) for PHP 7.2 specific issue.

that partially solved  my issue but can't able to override that file.

I tried using preference here's what I tried. 
`<preference for="Magento\Framework\File\Uploader" type="Vendor\Module\File\Uploader" />`

But doesn't seems to work. Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend not use Preferences, because there are other techniques that you could use to update the input or output of a function.

For example, you could write a Before plugin to update the incoming parameters or an After plugin to update the outgoing result.

But in your case, it probably is not possible with a Plugin but then you could use the Composer Patch technique.

More information about Composer Patching in Magento 2 you can find here:

> https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360005484154-Create-a-patch-for-a-Magento-2-Composer-installation-from-a-GitHub-commit

Answer (score 1):

I write at medium a post how to Patch your Magento:

https://medium.com/@LarsRoettig/how-to-apply-patches-on-magento-2-b4fd83537f61

I also don't strongly recommend to not use Preferences same reason as Mr. Lewis.

Answer (score 0):

We can override using preference.

- Create di.xml
- Create class php file

  ```
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <preference for="vendor\magento\framework\File\Uploader" type="NameSpace\Customer\Framework\File\Uploader" />
  ```
- In the given path put your fle `NameSpace\Customer\Framework\File\Uploader`

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this answer to solve your problem. This solution solves for success page. You can replace those with your file uploader...

[Refer Here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/268453)!