# Extend Magento 2 Onepage Success Block and success.phtml to display addition order information

Tags: magento2

I created a new module to display **order total** and some other information on Magento 2 success since page OOB success displays `order id` alone. Steps taken are below.

Created new Block that extends Onepage Success and added new method(s).
Copied OOB Onepage `success.phtml` to custom module `view\frontend\templates\mysuccess.phtml` and modified to call new methods from custom Block.

Added **di.xml** to replace OOB `<preference for="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success" type="VendorName\Checkout\Block\Onepage\CustomSuccess"/>`

Also created `view\frontend\layout\checkout_onepage_success.xml` with below entry to use new template phtml file.

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.success" template="VendorName_Checkout::mysuccess.phtml"/>
```

Also created **module.xml** and increased sequence number. Can anyone tell me what else do I need to use the new template and Block since I see blank success page instead of new block methods getting called?

I looked at [Call custom phtml on success page without override](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/136730/call-custom-phtml-on-success-page-without-override) and made similar changes but still no luck. What am I missing?
It's Magento 2.2.x CE.

Comment: did you get any error?

Comment: No errors, it wouldn't call any methods from the custom block and also doesn't display OOB order number and other information, all that section is blank on the success page with no errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can insert your own **`custom block`** by overriding **`checkout_onepage_success.xml`**
Try the below steps:

> 1. Create your **CustomSuccess.php** Block file in **vendor\module\Block\OnePage**

```
<?php
namespace vendor\module\Block\OnePage;
class CustomSuccess extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function getCustomSuccess()
    {
        return 'Your custom block contents.';
    }
}
```

> 2. Create **checkout_onepage_success.xml** layout file in **vendor\module\view\frontend\layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="order.success.additional.info">
        <block class="vendor\module\Block\OnePage\CustomSuccess"
               name="custom.order.success"
               template="Vendor_Module::order/success.phtml"
               after="-">
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

> 3. Lastly, create **phtml** template file in **vendor\module\view\frontend\templates\order**

```
<?php /* @var $block \vendor\module\Block\OnePage\CustomSuccess */?>
<?php echo __('This is a custom content.'); ?>
<?php echo $block->getCustomSuccess(); ?>
```

Don't forget to run the upgrade command and redeploy static view files.

Comment: I have made layout xml changes as above butt still not working. I may have mixed it up with changes from both answers, I am not sure if below custom module di.xml, and module.xml are necessary since the custom template should get data from the new Block and display after OOB success page. Am I right?

di.xml:
`<preference for="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success" type="Vendor\Checkout\Block\Onepage\CustomSuccess"/>`

module.xml:

`<module name="Vendor_Checkout" setup_version="2.0.0">
 <sequence>
   <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
 </sequence>
</module>`

Comment: I removed above mentioned entries from di.xml and module.xml and I still don't see custom phtml code being rendered though the module is enabled, ran upgrade and deployed static assets, cleared cache as well couple of times. Not sure what I am missing now.

Comment: At the end it was blank config entry in di.xml since layout entry already is referencing new Block and template phtml file as below. Other layout entry may have also worked but now left it with following and it's working now.
`<referenceContainer name="order.success.additional.info">
 <block class="VendoName\Checkout\Block\Onepage\CustomSuccess"
     name="custom.order.success"
     template="VendoName_Checkout::checkout/mysuccess.phtml"
     after="-">
 </block>
</referenceContainer>`

Comment: My bad, there was a lower case letter in the vendor name inside  checkout_onepage_success.xml while referencing the custom template, hence it wasn't called. I saw this issue in Developer mode but didn't enable it again since I thought I had fixed. It came up again since I was trying multiple things

Answer (score 4):

You can follow below file path to get additional order information to display order success page like order total.

> File path: magento/app/code/Vendor/OrderSuccess/registration.php

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_OrderSuccess',
    __DIR__
);
```

> File path: magento/app/code/Vendor/OrderSuccess/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_OrderSuccess" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> File path: magento/app/code/Vendor/OrderSuccess/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success" type="Vendor\OrderSuccess\Block\Onepage\CustomSuccess" />
</config>
```

> File path:
>   magento/app/code/Vendor/OrderSuccess/Block/Onepage/CustomSuccess.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\OrderSuccess\Block\Onepage;

class CustomSuccess extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success
{

    protected $orderItemsDetails;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Config $orderConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $orderItemsDetails,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $checkoutSession, $orderConfig, $httpContext, $data);
        $this->orderItemsDetails = $orderItemsDetails;
    }

    public function getOrderItemsDetails()
    {
        $IncrementId  = $this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder()->getIncrementId();
        $order = $this->orderItemsDetails->loadByIncrementId($IncrementId);
       return $order;
    }
}
```

> File path:
>   magento/app/code/Vendor/OrderSuccess/view/frontend/layout/checkout_onepage_success.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Vendor\OrderSuccess\Block\Onepage\CustomSuccess" name="checkout.successcustom" template="Vendor_OrderSuccess::mysuccess.phtml">
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> File path:
>   magento/app/code/Vendor/OrderSuccess/view/frontend/templates/mysuccess.phtml

```
<?php $_order = $block->getOrderItemsDetails(); ?>

<?php echo "Sub Total"; ?><?php echo $_order->formatPrice($_order->getSubTotal()); ?>
<?php echo "Grand Total"; ?> <?php echo $_order->formatPrice($_order->getGrandTotal()); ?>
```

Let me know if any query.

Hope it help!

Comment: @cnu your commented xml code only work for default template.

Comment: Thanks Kirti. I see below entry in OOB checkout_onepage_success.xml, and I don't see anything printed or called from the customsuccess.phtml, is there anything else that needs to be done to use custom template code after OOB template data?

Comment: `<referenceContainer name="content">
 <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success" name="checkout.success" template="Magento_Checkout::success.phtml" cacheable="false">
  <container name="order.success.additional.info" label="Order Success Additional Info"/>
 </block>
 <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Registration" name="checkout.registration" template="Magento_Checkout::registration.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
</referenceContainer>`